# Is there a simple way to recover the Doctrine Entity Manager from a class name?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a Symfony application with three doctrine Entity Managers, so I'm wondering if there is a web to revocer from a class name like \Company\Bundle\Entity\Classname the related Entity Manager.

So far I can iterate through the metadata with something like

```
$entities = array();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('manager_name');
$meta = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
foreach ($meta as $m) {
    // Compare classname with $m->getName() and return $em name
}
```

By I'm looking for a more "elegant" way.

Comment: You are right @qooplmao and your answer there is just what I've found 10 minutes ago. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Doctrine `ManagerRegistry` has a method `getManagerForClass`. That's what I was looking for.